# "at any time" vs "on any time" vs "in any time"? How use?

Tags: word-usage

For example:

Should I always mount with the `noinit_itable` option to mount all ext4 device at(or "on" or "in") any time?

If you can't understand above text then:

"Should I **always** mount with the `noinit_itable` option **to mount one** ext4 device at(or "on" or "in") any time?"this new text can more help you try guess my mean?please.

[link to context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/381092/7)

Comment: *Should I always **use** the "noinit_itable" option to mount all ext4 devices **at all times*** would be syntactically credible (but somewhat "awkward", due to excessive repetition of ***always, all***). But I'm not convinced any variant of ***any time*** can be used in your context. It's also not clear to me whether you're talking about always mounting all devices early on (so every one is then "ready for use" in subsequent processing), or always using that specific method when you *do* actually mount any given drive (so the procedure is "consistent").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure,but I think "always using that specific method when you do actually mount any given drive" is my mean.
I already post a [better version of context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/381092/5) to try make this ell question to clear.

Comment: Unless the intended sense is *always use this method, which allows all drives to be mounted **at once*** (i.e. - a single operation that mounts all potentially required drives in a single operation), I can't see what extra information or clarification you're trying to add by putting extra words after ***option*** in your cited suggestion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Should I **always** mount with the `noinit_itable` option **to mount one** ext4 device at(or "on" or "in") any time?"this new text can more help you try guess my mean?please.

Comment: Why don't you add a few more lines to the question text itself, describing exactly what technical procedure you're asking your (presumably, more *experienced*) colleague to give you advice on? These comments are only intended to help you improve the ELL question, not to actually contain vital additional information (note that comments may be deleted at any time, so your question still has to make sense if they are removed).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Why don't you add a few more lines to the question text itself" you mean should I add a link to [original context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381092/what-is-risk-or-cost-for-the-noinit-itable-option-of-ext4) to show what is "context"?

Comment: You absolutely ***should*** provide a link to that original context! I've just glanced at it - it's a bit technical, and I ***still*** don't fully understand exactly what that "noinit_itable" business is all about. But as regards the specific matter of ending the cited question with ***at(or "on" or "in") any time***, I still have absolutely no idea why you want to write ***anything*** there. You're already asking if you should ***always*** mount using the "noinit_itable" option, and it looks as if this only delays initialisation of ***one*** drive. Why mention ***any time*** at all?

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Why mention ***any time*** at all? " 
Because that [document](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt#L329) say quick install,so I guess it also quick for daily use,now I know that is not quick for daily use as [original context page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381092/what-is-risk-or-cost-for-the-noinit-itable-option-of-ext4).

Comment: But you've already dealt with that kind of "at any time" aspect by asking *should I **always** use this method?* And it hardly makes sense to ask whether you should always use it *at certain specific times* (such as only if you're mounting a disc in the morning, but not in the afternoon). You don't seem to be responding to the specific point I've been asking all the time here. Since you've already mentioned ***always***, what additional detail are you trying to include by adding extra text after ***to mount one ext4 device*** in your cited question? It simply makes no sense to me.

Comment: ...now I'm wondering if you're just trying to ask *Should I **always** use this option **whenever** I mount a drive?* In a context like that, either one of the highlighted words could be discarded - using both is perfectly valid, but all it does is add a certain amount of additional *emphasis*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-any-time), there is **"at any time"**, the other two don't exist. Also, looking at this [Dictionary](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) of examples, **"at any time"** is far more frequent than the other options, and when talking about time the most common preposition used is **"at"**.

Comment: Although to express that something is happening such that it is meeting a planned schedule, the phrase **on time** is used.